# How to ask good "Spanish Language meets X.SE" questions

Tags: soporte, ámbito

I have an idea for a "Spanish Language meets Law.SE" question.  I'd find it helpful to consult some guidelines for how to ask a good hybrid question.  Some do's and don't's.  Given that cross-posting is generally not allowed.

In short, how can I make it work?

Comment: La pregunta realmente es si tu pregunta es ontopic aqui. Que se pueda preguntar en otro sitio ya es otro cantar. Hay muchas preguntas con la etiqueta de vocabulario técnico que no se pueden responder bien sin ser bastante experto en la materia. No sé si tu pregunta es sobre vocabulario legal o sobre interpretación de jerga legal según diferencias regionales? Ayudaría que explicases un poco la pregunta

Comment: @Diego - The law question is an example.  Maybe I or others will want to ask other questions of this type later.  At any rate, if my question doesn't fly, it will get closed or maybe improved. // What I understood from Charlie is that the question might have some overlap with the other site but it must fundamentally be on topic here.

Comment: That's the point. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las preguntas tipo *Spanish Language meets `<your site>`* las inventé yo el día que hice [una pregunta que se podía responder usando un algoritmo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20685/12637), y pensé que lo mismo podría plantearla aquí que en Stack Overflow (en realidad no, porque SO está para resolver dudas, no para solicitar que alguien [te escriba un código](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19780/350184)), y entonces titulé la pregunta medio en broma como si fuera un *crossover* de ambos sitios. En aquel momento fue algo novedoso y no tenía muy claro si iba a ser una pregunta *on-topic*, pero yo me arriesgué igualmente y al final fue bien la cosa.

Luego probé suerte con [otra pregunta que acabó siendo cerrada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22482/12637), y ahora que lo veo con perspectiva se cerró con razón, dado que la pregunta podía ser igualmente formulada en inglés o en cualquier otro idioma que tenga los conceptos de *buscar* y *encontrar*.

Ya a partir de ahí parece que estas preguntas se están empezando a hacer populares [a raíz de mi último intento](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30747/12637). En realidad no es que haya reglas, es algo que me inventé y que la gente puede seguir si quiere. Lo único que no hay que perder de vista es **que la pregunta que se haga sea sobre el idioma español**, como cualquier otra pregunta del sitio. De hecho, una pregunta sobre el español usado en el ámbito del derecho sería muy relevante en el sitio (hasta la RAE ha publicado un diccionario sobre el español jurídico). El ejemplo de *[Spanish Language meets MathOverflow: What is the Spanish Homophonic Group?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27090/12637)* me parece muy interesante, porque tiene una fuerte componente de matemáticas (tuve que leerla varias veces para entenderla) pero en realidad si no conoces bien el idioma español no puedes responderla.

Resumiendo: podemos titular como "Spanish Language meets" aquellas preguntas que por su temática podrían tener cabida en otros sitios de la red, pero nunca sin perder de vista que debe ser una pregunta sobre el idioma español (y no una pregunta simplemente realizada en español o que trate el idioma de forma tangencial), y que por tanto solo pueda ser respondida en realidad por aquellos que conozcan bien el idioma.